# Picture library problem when breaking permission inheritance

Tags: permissions, picture-library, view

I have a picture library and I want to implement different permissions for users on the different levels in the library. But as soon as I break the inheritance for one folder strange things start to happen. Folders and pictures that were already uploaded would disappear. And I can no longer upload pictures in the library.

So I created a new library and created 3 nested folders in the following order:
[picture_library]/[folder_level1]/[folder_level2]/[folder_level3]

Then I broke the inheritance of permission for [folder_level3]. As soon as that happens i can no longer see folder_level3 and if i try to upload something in the same level (inside folder_level2) i get an error.

After investigating a bit I found that the url in the address bar was broken:

http://[my_site]/[picture_library]/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=[picture_library]/[folder_level1]&FolderCTID=0x012000B1182FEC5539F44FBAEC0D0351EE4E1F&&RootFolder=[picture_library]/[folder_level1]/[folder_level2]&FolderCTID=0x012000B1182FEC5539F44FBAEC0D0351EE4E1F

Notice that the query string parameters are doubled and there is a double '&' before the second ones. The correct query string is the second one witch "RootFolder" parameter points to [folder_level2] but somehow sharepoint carries the parameters from the folder on the previous level. When I remove the first set of parameters it works fine and all is well.

So finally, my question is have anyone encountered such a problem before? Is it a bug and how can i fix it? Thanks in advance.

PS: Actually I've just noticed that this issue exists only in Details view and not in Thumbnail or Filmstrip.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same behavior and was able to resolve it by editing the allitems.aspx view in SP Designer, converting the view into an custom XSLT data view, clicking on the item link in the preview window, Edit the XSLT on the surrouding href tag.
It initially showed as 
`<a href="{$thisNode/FileRef}{FilterLink}" target="_self">`

changed it to:`<a href="{$thisNode/FileRef}" target="_self">`

This appears to have resolved the problem.  It's a kludgy workaround, but it does work.